# Image in the folder is deleted but image path does not updated to null in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a code to delete image which is in a folder and to update image_path to null in the database. Although the image deletes the image, the path does not get updated to null. I spent hours to catch my mistake. But I could not. Any help would be grateful!

This is my code

```
<?php
//this is were images displayed
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE user_name='wendi'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
                   <a href="delete.php?delete=<?= $row['id'] ?>" onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"><img src="images/template/delete.png" id="AEDbutton">delete</a>

<?php
        echo "<img border=\"0\" src=\"" . $row['image_path4'] . "\" width=\"200\"  height=\"100\">";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}


?>
```

this is delete.php

```
<?php
include('config.php');


$sql    = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE user_name='wendi'";
$result = $con->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $image = $row['image_path4'];
    unlink($image);

}
$sql    = "UPDATE image_path4=null, file_name4=null FROM services WHERE user_name='wendi'";
$result = $con->query($sql);


?>
```

Comment: You have an extra comma in `file_name4=null, FROM`

Comment: @NigelRen I removed it, but still imagepath does not updated

Comment: Check for Errors after executing SQL statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `UPDATE` query is malformed, [the syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html) should be like this:

```
UPDATE {table} SET {column}={value} WHERE {column2}={value2}
```

So in your case this would be:

```
UPDATE services SET image_path4=null, file_name4=null WHERE user_name='wendi'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE services SET image_path4 = null, file_name4 = null WHERE user_name = 'wendi' ";
```

Answer (score 1):

After uplink function assign `$image` to `null`:

```
$image = null;
```

And use update query below:

```
$sql = "UPDATE  `services ` SET  `image_path4` = ' ". $image." ', `file_name4` = ' ". $image." ' WHERE `user_name` = 'wendi' ";
```